# PostgreSQL not creating TCP connection using informix_fwd

Tags: postgresql, informix, foreign-data-wrapper

I'm trying to access InformixDB from ***PostgreSQL*** using *informix_fwd*.
I've already created foreign server, user mapping and foreign table.
I'm monitoring netstat while trying to query foreign table, but no connections are listed in output and query ends with following error:
`ERROR:  could not open connection to informix server: SQLCODE=-908`

***PostgreSQL*** and ***InformixDB*** are one separated servers, telnet and dbaccess works.

Comment: Can you connect to this informix from some other tool, on the same machine as PostgreSQL is running and from the same OS user that is running PostgreSQL?

Comment: Review the connection details for the Informix server (INFORMIXSERVER, machine, tcp service) and try connecting from one of the tools included with the informix client (ilogin.exe) it may give you a little bit more detail

Comment: I can successfully connect using Informix Client SDK (dbaccess tool).
Also connection details are correct in $INFORMIXDIR\etc\sqlhosts file.

Comment: dbaccess uses the connection info from the sqlhosts file but the CSDK APIs (esql/ODBC/OLEDB) which is what PostgreSQL will uses, expect to have that information in the Windows registry (through setnet32.exe).
CSDK tools like ilogin.exe or Connecttest.exe would be a better test.

Comment: I'm using Linux, not Windows.

Comment: ok, then forget about setnet32. informix_fwd uses ESQL/C (same as dbaccess) so assuming the environment and configuration is the same in both cases, if one works, the other should too. Are you sure they are both using the same SQLHOSTS file? What if you rename the file, do you get a 25596 error instead?

Comment: Both are using same SQLHOSTS file. I tested to change content of SQLHOSTS file and then the error while using informix_fwd was different.
I think there is something with Postgres, maybe it needs to be configured to allow its session to access foreign hosts? The point is, when I try to access remote database with informix_fwd, I can't see anything in the NETSTATS output  related to this attemp. I think something prevents on Postgres server to create connection to Informix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi all and thanks for response.
The problem was with SELinux configuration. I temporarily disabled SELinux and everything works fine.